# Notepad space removal issue

Tags: notepad++

I have attached a small piece of the list below.

You can download the file by going to: http://speedy.sh/JunQS/testsssssss.txt

As you can see from the text file, it is in this format:

username    :     password

I need it to be in the following format:

username:password

If you take a look at the file I've given above you will understand my scenario.

I have spent the last hour and half browsing through Stackoverflow, and other sites with no luck. Nothing seems to be working so if one of you guys find a fix Id be quite surprised.

Comment: Is it impossible to press backspace?

Comment: I have around 25,000 lines..

Comment: If it's the file you linked, it has 6 lines. Otherwise fair enough

Answer (score 0):

Windows Notepad?

CTRL+h

Search for: SPACE
replace with: NOTHING OR NULL

Is that what you are looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of encoding are you using?  UTF or ANSI?  What is generating this?  I think you need to give us some more detail as to what you are doing?  Otherwise, you are going to have to use something a bit more powerful than Windows Notepad - Like TextPad, Ultraedit, EditPad..

Comment: I have attached a small piece of the list below.

You can download the file by going to: http://speedy.sh/JunQS/testsssssss.txt

As you can see from the text file, it is in this format:

username : password

I need it to be in the following format:

username:password

If you take a look at the file I've given above you will understand my scenario.

I have spent the last hour and half browsing through Stackoverflow, and other sites with no luck. Nothing seems to be working so if one of you guys find a fix Id be quite surprised.

Answer (score 0):

There are tabulators between colons.
If you have notepad++ just remove them by regexp:
Search/Find/Replace
Search Mode: Regular expression
Find what: \t
Replace with:

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in NPP will bring up Find/Replace. Switch to the Replace tab and use these values:

Find what: `\s`
Replace with:  (blank)

Then in Search Mode, use Regular Expression and hit Replace All. Job done.